# Angular string and number validation error

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Protokol Detayı" type="text" required="true" name="detail" id="detail"
                                    #detail="ngModel" ngModel required>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-error *ngIf="detail.touched && detail.invalid">
    <div *ngIf="detail.errors.required">Bu alanı boş geçemezsiniz.</div>
</mat-error>
```

I want to show an error if the input gets number instead of letters. But I could not manage to do it. I think I am right in writing the type of the input.

Comment: it is perfectly correct to type numbers in "text" input type

Comment: Yes but what i want to show is the error if someone typed a number.

Comment: you can use regex expression and set it to pattern attribute

Comment: @Gautam could you please clarify?

Comment: @n.ah93 please check the answer below if it suits your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you could achieve this.
1] Do not allow numbers to be entered in the input box. Display no errors
2] use pattern attribute on input and display errors when the entered text does not match the input
 for example the following pattern will take only alphabets and will give error when the user enters numbers.

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Protokol Detayı" type="text" required="true" name="detail" id="detail"
                                    #detail="ngModel" [pattern]="[a-zA-Z]+$" ngModel required>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-error *ngIf="detail.touched && detail.invalid">
        <div *ngIf="detail.errors.required">Bu alanı boş geçemezsiniz.</div>
        <div *ngIf="detail.errors.pattern">numbers not allowed.</div>

    </mat-error>
```